# change the position of already packed widget in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button, position, pack

Here is the code,

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

update_button = Button(root, text='Update')
update_button.pack()


def button():
    frame1 = Frame(root)
    frame1.pack()

    button1 = Button(frame1, text="Button 1")
    button1.pack(side=LEFT)

    button2 = Button(frame1, text="Button 2")
    button2.pack(side=LEFT)


button()

root.mainloop()
```

I want button1 to be stacked upon button2 when I click update button.
Help please.

Comment: Simply call `pack_forget()` on the buttons and then `pack()` again to the way you want.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, but could you please tell me how to use pack_forget() in the above code so that I can understand it better, please.

Comment: Are you aware that you can set the side to `"top"` to arrange widgets in a vertical stack?

Comment: yes I am aware. But I want those 2 buttons at "top" in one condition and at the "left" in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I want button1 to be stacked upon button2 when I click update button.
```

The problem can be fixed.

- Create `button_1()` function.
- Add `button1.pack` inside `button_1()` function.
- Move `frame1` and `button1` widget outside of function.

That all!

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def button_1():     
    button1.pack(side=TOP)

frame1 = Frame(root)    
button1 = Button(frame1, text="Button 1")

update_button = Button(root, text='Update', command=button_1)
update_button.pack()

def button():
    frame1.pack()
    
    button1.pack(side=LEFT)

    button2 = Button(frame1, text="Button 2")
    button2.pack(side=LEFT)


button()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]